# Implementing 802.1x on FreeBSD

Tags: authentication, freebsd, hostapd

I'm trying to implement 802.1x authenticator on FreeBSD, using hostapd. When I run the daemon, this is what I get:

```
Starting hostapd.
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=21, val=0, arg_len=42]: Invalid argument
Could not connect to kernel driver.
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=21, val=0, arg_len=42]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=17, val=0, arg_len=0]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=20, val=0, arg_len=7]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=20, val=0, arg_len=7]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=20, val=0, arg_len=7]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=20, val=0, arg_len=7]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=1, arg_len=32]: Invalid argument
Could not read SSID from system
em0: Unable to setup interface.
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=21, val=0, arg_len=42]: Invalid argument
Could not connect to kernel driver.
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=21, val=0, arg_len=42]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCS80211, op=7, val=4, arg_len=0]: Invalid argument
/etc/rc.d/hostapd: WARNING: failed to start hostapd
```

And then it changes my interface to down.
This is my hostapd.conf:

```
interface=em0
\#driver=wired
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=1
debug=2
dump_file=/tmp/hostapd.dump
ieee8021x=1
eap_reauth_period=3600
use_pae_group_addr=1
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
nas_identifier=ap.example.com
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=radius
acct_server_addr=127.0.0.1
acct_server_port=1813
acct_server_shared_secret=radius
```

Thanks

Comment: the ioctl SIOCS80211 looks like it only works with wireless lan interfaces, and em(4) is a wired interface. Why did you commend out the line #driver=wired ??

Comment: Because it wouldn't find the "wired" driver. But it seems that it should be the right driver.

Comment: sorry, can't help any further. i suggest to take this up on a freebsd mailinglist, maybe freebsd-net@FreeBSD.org